# Proving the unboundedness of a particular real-valued sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> **Proposition** Suppose that $ (x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ is a sequence in $ \mathbb{R} $ such that
>   $$
> \forall m,n \in \mathbb{N}: \quad m > n ~~ \Longrightarrow ~~ |x_{m} - x_{n}| > \frac{1}{n}.
> $$
>   Then $ (x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ is unbounded.

I can somehow show that $ \displaystyle \text{Diam} \left( \{ x_{n} \}_{n=1}^{N} \right) > \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n} $ for all $ N \in \mathbb{N} $, but the details are messy. Might there be a slicker proof? Thank you very much!

Comment: Great question, +1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every $n$, let $I_n=(x_n-\frac1{2n},x_n+\frac1{2n})$. Assume that for some $n\lt m$, there exists $x$ in $I_n\cap I_m$. Then $|x_n-x_m|\leqslant|x-x_n|+|x-x_m|\lt\frac1{2n}+\frac1{2m}\lt\frac1n$, which is absurd. Hence $I_n\cap I_m$ is empty for every $n\ne m$.
In particular, the set $J=\bigcup\limits_nI_n$ has Lebesgue measure $\sum\limits_n\frac1n$, which is infinite, thus $J$ is not bounded. For every $M\gt0$ there exists $x$ in $J$ such that $|x|\gt M$. By definition of $J$, this implies that there exists $n$ such that $|x_n|\geqslant|x|-|x-x_n|\gt M-1$, hence the sequence $(x_n)_n$ is not bounded.

Note that one can replace $\frac1n$ by some positive $a_n$, as long as the series $\sum\limits_na_n$ diverges.

Comment: This is more than good enough! +1. :)

Comment: Cool. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: This is perfect, congrats and +1. Atually, I wish I could give more than +1 on this one.

Comment: @julien Thanks. (Actually, I just modified a step of the proof using contradiction, unnecessarily so.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I have been working on, which avoids measure theory. I have managed to simplify my original argument, so it is now worthy of being posted! :)

> Let $ N \in \mathbb{N} $.
>
> > 1. Observe that the terms of $ (x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ are distinct.
> > 2. Find a permutation $ \sigma: \{ 1,\ldots,N + 1 \} \to \{ 1,\ldots,N + 1 \} $ that makes $ (x_{\sigma(n)})_{n=1}^{N+1} $ a strictly increasing sequence.
> > 3. Let $ n \in \{ 1,\ldots,N \} $.
> >
> >    - If $ \sigma(n + 1) > \sigma(n) $, then the hypothesis yields $ x_{\sigma(n + 1)} - x_{\sigma(n)} > \dfrac{1}{\sigma(n)} $.
> >    - If $ \sigma(n + 1) < \sigma(n) $, then the hypothesis yields $ x_{\sigma(n + 1)} - x_{\sigma(n)} > \dfrac{1}{\sigma(n + 1)} $. Hence, as $ \dfrac{1}{\sigma(n + 1)} > \dfrac{1}{\sigma(n)} $, we also obtain $ x_{\sigma(n + 1)} - x_{\sigma(n)} > \dfrac{1}{\sigma(n)} $.
> > 4. We thus have the following:
> >        \begin{align}
> >          \sum_{n=1}^{N} \left[ x_{\sigma(n + 1)} - x_{\sigma(n)} \right]
> >    &>    \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{\sigma(n)}. \quad
> >          (\text{Telescoping sum on the left-hand side.}) \\
> >          x_{\sigma(N + 1)} - x_{\sigma(1)}
> >    &>    \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{\sigma(n)} \quad
> >          (\text{After evaluating the telescoping sum.}) \\
> >    &=    \left[ \sum_{n=1}^{N+1} \frac{1}{\sigma(n)} \right] -
> >          \frac{1}{\sigma(N + 1)} \quad (\text{Adding and subtracting.}) \\
> >    &=    \left[ \sum_{n=1}^{N+1} \frac{1}{n} \right] - \frac{1}{\sigma(N + 1)}
> >          \quad (\text{As $ \sigma $ is a permutation.}) \\
> >    &\geq \left[ \sum_{n=1}^{N+1} \frac{1}{n} \right] - 1 \quad
> >          (\text{As $ \sigma(N + 1) \geq 1 $.}) \\
> >    &=    \sum_{n=2}^{N+1} \frac{1}{n}.
> >    \end{align}
> > 5. Hence,
> >        $$
> >      \text{Diam} \left( \{ x_{n} \}_{n=1}^{N+1} \right)
> >    = \left( \max_{1 \leq n \leq N + 1} x_{n} \right) -
> >      \left( \min_{1 \leq n \leq N + 1} x_{n} \right)
> >    > \sum_{n=2}^{N+1} \frac{1}{n}.
> >    $$
>
> As $ N \in \mathbb{N} $ is arbitrary, it follows from the divergence of the Harmonic Series that $ \text{Diam} \left( \{ x_{n} \}_{n=1}^{\infty} \right) = \infty $.

**Conclusion:** $ (x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty} $ is an unbounded sequence in $ \mathbb{R} $.